# How to gather all the files and the folders that was generated with pyinstaller except the executable (kivy application)

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I am building a kivy application, I convert it into an executable with PyInstaller and it work very well, but the issue is that there are lot of files (.dll, .pyd...etc) that are generated with Myapp.exe in the same folder. i want to give the app to several users and i want to put all the files and folders in one folder or 2 maximum except Myapp.exe.

I had this for another application because the cx_freeze did it by generating the lib folder. Pyinstaller did not generate this folder, it display all files in the same folder as the executable.

Any one can provide me a solution to this issue please ?

here is my .spec :

```
block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

a = Analysis(['Myapp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\\\deskapp\\Code'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['os','pandas','sys','kivy'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree                       
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)
dict_tree = Tree('C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\deskapp\\Code\\kv Scripts', prefix='kv Scripts', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
dict_tree = Tree('C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\deskapp\\Code\\Images_logo', prefix='Images', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree    
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='My app',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          icon = 'C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\deskapp\\Code\\Images_logo\\MyIcon.ico',
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
                Tree('C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\share\\glew\\bin\\'),
                Tree('C:\\HOMEWARE\\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\share\\sdl2\\bin\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='My app')
```

And this is what i get in dist folder (where the exe is generated):

[image]

and this is what i want (or something like this) :

[image]

When i use the **cx_freeze** with `base = 'Win32GUI'`, My application doesn't appear, i have just **cx_Freeze: Python error in main script** as a title of my App and i can't see what was the cause.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, i used the cx_freeze with `base =  'Win32GUI'`, the problem was caused by logs which can not be displayed in the gui when we use `'Win32GUI'`.

I tried to direct them to a log file but I did not succeed, so I went to the `__init__.py` file in the `\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\Lib\logging` folder and I commented on the line number 999 and I replaced it with `pass`. It ain't stupid if it works, hop this will help some one. let me know if you have another solution.

here is the code in `__init__py` :

[image: screenshot]